# Twitter Bootstrap Javascript Carousel Multiple Active Item Transition

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, carousel

In the examples I found so far, all of them either displaying one Item at a time. If I want to display multiple active items using thumbnails, examples show that the Item itself containing multiple thumbnail inside of it. When I press 'Next' or 'Previous' buttons, 'active' class is being set to another item so all of the contents of the item is being replaced.

I want to display multiple active Items inside of the 'carousel-inner' class. I managed to do that but unfortunately the 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons stopped working. Below is the workaround i tried so far. For example, **I want to move two of the active Items per 'Next' or 'Previous' button click**. Any suggestion?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://ucsdnews.ucsd.edu/graphics/images/2009/11-09OceanRobots01.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://www.nmsfocean.org/files/windfarm-250x250.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>                       
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://www.notempire.com/images/uploads/Conserve_Our_Oceans-2.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://www.northcountrypublicradio.org/news/images/blacksmokervent_250.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jTLcTU1RvZc/Ts11y1haQqE/AAAAAAAAALk/xYJoRFK-ibw/s250-c-k-no/OceanSunfish" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://tcktcktck.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/ocean-heat.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/carousel-inner-->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
```

I am working on Angular JS project. So any angular solution will be highly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935389/possible-to-show-two-slides-in-the-carousel-at-a-time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

group element that you want to display together in item class div

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://ucsdnews.ucsd.edu/graphics/images/2009/11-09OceanRobots01.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://www.nmsfocean.org/files/windfarm-250x250.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>                       
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://www.notempire.com/images/uploads/Conserve_Our_Oceans-2.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://www.northcountrypublicradio.org/news/images/blacksmokervent_250.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jTLcTU1RvZc/Ts11y1haQqE/AAAAAAAAALk/xYJoRFK-ibw/s250-c-k-no/OceanSunfish" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <a href="#x" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://tcktcktck.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/ocean-heat.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/carousel-inner-->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: your provided code was the existing example. I changed it according to my requirement. Since I am using Angular JS ng-repeat, I can not group the items.

Comment: In jquery you can modify html..so after resulted default html ..you can modify in you way..

Comment: i guess i need to change the jquery code for moving the 2 items at a time