# Angular-JS Carousal with multiple slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a carousel as follows:

```
<div>
    <carousel id="myC" interval="3000" >            
       <slide ng-repeat="order in orders">
          <img ng-src="whatever.jpg" style="margin:auto;">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h4>Order {{$index}}</h4>
                  <p>{{order.title}}</p>
                </div>
       </slide> 
</div>
```

This works fine. But i am looking for following behavior:
1. Display multiple slides (say 5) at a time.
2. Instead of img, i want to display DIVs. The idea is to display Order information in rectangular DIVs, and they can slide left or right (like a carousel)

Or any other ideas to do the same thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you have seen this before: 
[Possible to show two slides in the carousel at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935389/possible-to-show-two-slides-in-the-carousel-at-a-time)

Hope this helps.