# Dynamically change number of slides displayed in 1 frame of carousel

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to AngularJS. Right now I have a reusable carousel widget that I modified to display 2 slides in one frame (I make my carousel as a directive so I can use it anywhere). I am using carousel component from angular-ui-bootstrap, and I modified it according to the way explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935389/possible-to-show-two-slides-in-the-carousel-at-a-time?lq=1).

However, I am planning to modify my current carousel widget to accept a number that will determine how many slides will be displayed in 1 frame, and dynamically changes its display.

For example, if 3 is passed, then 3 slides will be displayed in 1 frame.

The way I have my 2-slides-in-1-frame carousel widget is pretty static (the number of slides shown in 1 frame is already defined in its HTML). Is it possible to do this? Any help is really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Angular Slick?
https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to modify the angular-ui-bootstrap carousel, just display a row with two or three columns inside the carousel.

This is a my fork of the original angular-ui-bootstrap carousel plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/F2h3gIQKzpkjymZDgrK6

The short version is:

```
<slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            ... first cell
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            ... second cell
        </div>
    </div>
</slide>
```

Then what you can do is create your own templating directive that does the math on how many columns to display (2 = col-xs-6, 3 = col-xs-4, ... ) and renders the above partial with the appropriate column classes.

Comment: hmm quick question -- in this example, isn't first cell and second cell displaying the same slide?

Comment: Yep. I was demonstrating how to split up the slide into multiple columns.

Comment: ah I see. is it possible to do this with different slides?

Comment: So what you would want to do is on the second column show the image $index ± 1. In the ng-repeat use a modulo filter to skip every other image in the list.