# angular-carousel with multiple items

Tags: angularjs, angular-carousel

i want to create carousel using angular-carousel library.
    i want to display 3 slides at a time and while swiping it should swipe only one item.

```
here is the link for ref. angular-carousel :https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel

ex. 
//this is just html code
<ul rn-carousel class="image">
  <li ng-repeat="image in sportImages">
    <div class="layer">{{ image }}</div>
  </li>
</ul>

lets assume i have 100 images and i want to display 3 image slides at a time. right now i am able to display one slide at a time . what should i do to display  3 slides at a time? any suggestion ?

any help would be really good.
```

Comment: Possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935389/possible-to-show-two-slides-in-the-carousel-at-a-time

Comment: have you gone through this link : https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel , this library i have to use. i am not usign twitter-bootstrap.